# sphinx is showing the django base views instead of my own views.py

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

The view being shown when using Sphinx on a Django site is:
[image]

The beginning of my views.py is:

```
import os
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.urls import reverse 
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect 
from django.utils import timezone
from . forms import PlayForm, RollForm, checkBoard, BossForm
from random import randint 
from . templatetags.playExtras import translateDice 
from .models import Board, Winner, Boss

def getFirstFolder(req):
    """ return the string between first two / - this is a hack, find out how to do it with the object """
    r = req.split("'")
    loc = r[1].find('/',1)
    x = r[1][1:loc]
    return(x)

def loadBoard(request,context,location=''):
    ''' Load the board from the database into context. Add a hyperlink for available squares.

    :param context: context for template
    :type context: dictionary

    :param location: Comma seperated string of available locations or empty string so no links included.
    :type location: str

    :return: 'not on the board' or 'all taken' or comma seperated string of location options such as 'A0,B0'
    :rtype: str    
    '''
    req = request.__str__()
```

I was getting errors if I didn't show Sphinx where the Python was located. The path additions I made in the Sphinx's conf.py are:

```
ourPaths = [
    '/game/',
    '/game/game',
    '/game/play',
    '/game/play/templatetags'
    ]
for p in ourPaths:
    abspath = os.path.abspath('.')  + p
    print('path..................',abspath)
    sys.path.insert(0, abspath)
# Need to point to where the Django is on this system. FIND OUT HOW TO MAKE THIS RELATIVE
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/ajp/Downloads/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0,'/home/ajp/Downloads/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django')
```

The views.rst file I'm using:

```
views module
==============

.. automodule:: views
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

I searched for days but I'm afraid I do not know the right terms search for to find the answer.

I'm okay with the other code showing up, but I'd need to see my code in the manual as well.

Thank you for any help you can give.

Answer (score 0):

Tony Flury on django-users@googlegroups.com pointed to other explorations. I eventually found that Jens Hedegaard Nielsen gave the answer (indirectly) at https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/4182. There he pointed to

autodoc_mock_imports = ["django"]

in the Sphinx documentation http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports

Answer (score 0):

The autodoc_mock_imports solution worked in some cases, but the larger my project got the more I had to "jury-rig" to keep it working, to I finally gave up and waited to take another stab at it. This week Doris Wang and I tried building sphinx in the virtualenv that we were using for Django and it worked fine. On the Debian system I'm using, I used:

```
python -m pip install sphinx
```

within the environment to install sphinx.